# Spread sheet Data import engine

Tags: excel, csv, import

We are developing a web application which has a requirement of importing  spread sheet data of any format like excel or  database  table and  parse  into csv (with first column as heading) and re-import it into our data grid

We are looking to develop it ground up (may be trying to re-invent the wheel)

I would appreciate if anyone provides me logic/pointers
Any coding language php/java/c# is fine ; I am more or less looking at the logic

Answer (score 0):

For a PHP solution, take a look at [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net)